# Does new version of Swiper JS support old browsers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, swiper.js

Just a query on Browser compatibiity.
I want to use Swiper JS latest version 8.4.5 in my project. Currently SwiperJS 4.1.6 is used .
I can see on their shared Github repository file `.browserslistrc`, there are changes with which targets below browsers,

```
Samsung >= 12
IOS >= 12
last 5 Chrome versions
Safari >= 12
last 5 Firefox versions
```

Does this mean that Other browsers (Opera, Edge, Android Web View) and old versions of browser not supported?
Is there any page link for SwiperJS that describes browser compatibility?

Some older browser versions are,

```
Safari-> 9.0
Chrom-> 99.108.0.0
Edge-> 99.0.1150.55
Samsung Internet-> 11.0
Firefox-> 102.0
Abdroid webView-> 100.0
Safari(In App)-> 15.0
Amazon Silk-> 50.2

Opera-> 6.03
IE-> 5.50
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the "older browsers"? Which version(s) are you referring to? Have you already tested it by running it on older browsers?

Comment: @node_modules Added older browser example to my question

Answer (score 0):

Try also asking at github, or the primary persons directly involved in the project. Its presumable that one of them already is on some kind of cross browser testing service plan such as BrowserStack. Who knows, one of them might go the extra mile if its 1-2 additional browsers.

If you just want to check your own live hosted existing SwiperJS on your own website so as to verify its functionality on some of those older browsers for compatibility:

-Cross browser emulator or simulators

-Web developer Tools

-Virtual Machine

-LambdaTest

-IETester (free)

-Test IE (for chrome - checks IE6 through IE11).

-A testing service provider such a BrowserStack.com